# React Native Animated - Start animation at touch location

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, react-animated

I'm playing around with animation in React Native. Want to build a Screen that allows a user to touch the screen at any point. When they do, a circle should appear at the location of their finger, and follow it around. When they release, the circle should shrink back to nothing.

I started following [this tutorial](https://mindthecode.com/getting-started-with-the-panresponder-in-react-native/), which is for a spring-like animation, in which you drag a preexisting square (which starts in the center of the screen), and it springs back on release.

In my case, the circle should have **no** preexisting location, and this is causing the problem. If I initialize my component state, with, say, `pan: new Animated.ValueXY()`, and then touch the screen, the circle starts in the upper left corner, **not** where my finger is. I've tried a variety of other solutions, all replacing the commented line in the onPanResponderGrant method below, but can't seem to figure it out.

How do I have an animation that simply has the component track my finger without starting or returning anywhere?

Here's the code for the component:

```
class FollowCircle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      pan: new Animated.ValueXY(),
      scale: new Animated.Value(0)
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,

      onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
        // This is the line I'm playing with
        this.state.pan.setValue({ x: this.state.pan.x._value, y: this.state.pan.y._value });

        Animated.spring(
          this.state.scale,
          { toValue: 1, friction: 3 },
        ).start();
      },

      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
        null, { dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: this.state.pan.y }
      ]),

      onPanResponderRelease: (/* e, gestureState */) => {
        this.state.pan.flattenOffset();
        Animated.spring(
          this.state.scale,
          {
            toValue: 0,
            friction: 10,
            restDisplacementThreshold: 1
          },
        ).start();
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { pan, scale } = this.state;
    const circleStyles = {
      backgroundColor: 'black',
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      borderRadius: 25,
      transform: [
        { translateX: pan.x },
        { translateY: pan.y },
        { scale }
      ]
    };

    return (
      <AppWrapper navigation={ this.props.navigation }>
        <Animated.View
          style={ {
            flex: 1,
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
            height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
            backgroundColor: 'white'
          } }
          { ...this._panResponder.panHandlers }
        >
          <Animated.View
            style={ circleStyles }
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </AppWrapper>
    );
  }
};
```

And here are my alternative attempts (replacements for the commented line):

```
this.state.pan.setValue({ x: gestureState.x0, y: gestureState.y0 });
```

And this one:

```
  if (this.state.pan) {
    this.state.pan.setValue({ x: this.state.pan.x._value, y: this.state.pan.y._value });
  } else {
    this.setState({ pan: new Animated.ValueXY(gestureState.x0, gestureState.y0) });
  }
```

Both seem to behave similarly, resetting the circle location in the upper left after each movement, and not quite tracking my finger location unless I start my touch at that origin.

Any ideas how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out by replacing the `panResponder` stuff with a page-sized `TouchableHighlight`, with an `onTouch` event.

That event triggered the following function, which gets the `nativeEvent.pageX` and `pageY` location, and uses that. I had to make some slight alterations for the `y` location, to make it work across phones:

```
  triggerSwipe({ nativeEvent }) {
    const coordinates = { x: nativeEvent.pageX, y: nativeEvent.pageY };
    const self = this;
    if (!this.state.animating) {
      this.setState({
        x: coordinates.x,
        y: coordinates.y + (this.windowHeight / 2.5),
        animating: true
      }, () => {
        Animated.timing(
          self.state.scale,
          { toValue: 20, duration: 600 },
        ).start(() => {
          this.setState({
            scale: new Animated.Value(0.01), // See Notes.md for reasoning
            colorIndex: this.state.colorIndex + 1,
            animating: false
          });
        });
      });
    }
```

The animating circle is an `Animated.View` inside the `TouchableHighlight`, which is fed the coordinates of the touch.